# Mask image using transparent map in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I have two images. First one is a grayscale gradient image:

[image]

Second one is a mask:

[image]

What I need is to hide part of the first image corresponding to the transparent area of the second image. It is very similar to the alpha mapping but I don't know how to implement it without inverting of mask image or writing custom shader.

Comment: Various materials like `MeshPhongMaterial` provide an [alphaMap](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/MeshPhongMaterial.alphaMap) property. Have you tried to apply your mask texture to it and then set `material.alphaTest` to e.g. `0.5`.

Comment: @Mugen87 Thank you for response! I tried to use `alphaTest` but did not get the desired result unfortunately. For now I desided to negate mask image.